# ASP.NET WEB API Error While Updating Database with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, api

I am new to WEB API, I have problem with crud operations-update

**Auto-generated model class which is**

```
public partial class CUSTOMER
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string SURNAME { get; set; }
    public string BIRTHPLACE { get; set; }
    public string GENDER { get; set; }
    public string IDENTITYNO { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IDENTITYPINCODE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> BIRTHDATE { get; set; }
}
```

**and I have a class which I save CRUD operations**

```
public class CustomerCRUD
{
    AlishEntities db = new AlishEntities();

    public CUSTOMER UpdateCustomer(int id, CUSTOMER updatingCustomer)
    {
        db.Entry(updatingCustomer).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return updatingCustomer;
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class SqlCrudController : ApiController
{
    CustomerCRUD crud = new CustomerCRUD();

    public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, Models.CUSTOMER customer)
    {
      return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, crud.UpdateCustomer(id, customer));
    }
}
```

**When I test it with postman it says:**

> "ExceptionMessage": "Store update, insert, or delete statement
>   affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been
>   modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

Comment: Are you sure a Customer with that key exists in the database?

Comment: I can do all operations, get, get by id, delete, post. there is nth wrong with the key

Comment: Thre's nothing obviously wrong with the code you posted.  Using just the CustomerCRUD and CUSTOMER class create a unit test that reproduces the issue.

Comment: can you pls help me to solve this problem?

Comment: public void UpdateCustomer(int id, CUSTOMER updatingCustomer)
        {
            var NewUser = db.CUSTOMERs.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);

            NewUser.NAME = updatingCustomer.NAME;

Comment: this method works, but when you send request with postman, you need to apply all properties,  { "name":"test1", "surname":"test2" ....} but the first method is both short and you dont need to specify all properties. just { "name" :"test1"} other columns wont be equal null whereas columns will be null if you dont specify data it self when you send a request.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft you got me